# What are signs of a ready liquid levain culture?

Tags: bread, sourdough-starter

I made a starter from the Jeffrey Hamelman's book. Currently I am on day 6. For those unfamiliar these are the steps:

**Day 1** 100% whole-rye flour | 125% water | 3.3% honey

**Day 2** 111% starter | 50% whole-rye | 50% wheat white flour | 125% water

**Day 3** and onwards 111% starter | 100% wheat white flour | 125% water

In the past I used equal parts water and rye flour to create my starter and I was feeding it 1:1:1. The starter was doubling in volume and signs of readiness were obvious.

However things seem to be a bit different with the liquid one. It used to rise in volume during day 1 and 2, but around day 3 when only wheat white flour was used for feeding and it started to be more liquidy it almost stopped rising in volume. After some time I see tiny bubbles on the surface, but that's about it. I experimented with different temperatures and I tried this recipe few times and I am wondering if this is common for this type of starter? Are the bubbles on top the only sign of a healthy alive starter and it won't rise so much in volume?

It smells nice, but the thing that bothers me is lack of volume rise, cause everybody says starter should rise in volume and the top should be a bit curved.

Comment: `liquid Levain Culture` is a liquid sourdough starter.  I failed to find a reliable link for a definition.

Comment: Yes, the thing is some say liquid starter is 100% hydration, others its 500% hydration. I couldn't find anything with 125% except the book and this extra 25% makes it behave differently.